# JFrame Form Source file error

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am developing a login Form in net beans 8.0.1 using MVC model, there's no error through out the code but the autoamtic generated code in JFRAME source file, there's a error in the class of JFRAME. the error says: `duplicate class: com.innovatraasolutions.eev.ui.loginform`?
There's no existence of that class throughout the project.!

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.innovatraasolutions.eev.ui;

import com.innovatraasolutions.eev.controller.Controller;
import com.innovatraasolutions.eev.constants.Constants;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiderMan
 */
**public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame//**there's an error**** {

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginForm
     */
    public LoginForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        unameTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        pwdTxt = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        loginBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        errorMsgLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("                Effective Electronic Vote");

        jLabel2.setText("UserName:");

        jLabel3.setText("Password:");

        loginBtn.setText("Login");
        loginBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                loginBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        errorMsgLbl.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        errorMsgLbl.setText("Invalid Username or password");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 263, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(153, 153, 153)
                            .addComponent(loginBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 138, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                            .addComponent(errorMsgLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 308, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jSeparator1)
                                    .addComponent(pwdTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 228, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(unameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 228, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(206, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(unameTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 17, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(pwdTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(loginBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(errorMsgLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(134, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void loginBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        Object[] parameters = new Object[2]; //Generic Parameters to catch the username and password from the Text box and Password feild
        Object returnobj = null;
        parameters[0] = unameTxt.getText();
        parameters[1] = pwdTxt.getPassword(); 
       returnobj = controller.processRequest(Constants.LoginAction , parameters);
       if(returnobj== null)
       {
           errorMsgLbl.setVisible(true);
           //show the error Message here because the returnobj is null
       }
       else //Verfication Done
       {
           //Create new form hide this form and show the new form

       }
    }                                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        errorMsgLbl.setVisible(false);
    }                                 

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel errorMsgLbl;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JButton loginBtn;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField pwdTxt;
    private javax.swing.JTextField unameTxt;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Perform a "clean" of the project and then try rebuilding it.  Try restarting netbeans.  If all else fails, delete the cache directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***This is a known issue for Netbeans IDE***

You need to clear Netbeans cache :

Go to Help -> About and you will see

Cache directory: dir_path

go to that directory and delete everything.

Comment: I have located the Cache Folder but there are alot of folders in the Cache folder. Which folder should be deleted?

Comment: under that folder search for the class i.e. 'LoginForm' and delete that folder

Comment: Thnxs alot Brother...!